# Can bash completion be invoked programmatically?

Tags: bash, api, bash-completion

What I want is a function I can call from a program so it completes the way bash would given a commandline and a location where TAB was pressed.

```
. /etc/bash_completion
generate_completions "command arg1 arg2" 17
```

would return the same thing as

```
command arg1 arg2[TAB]
```

I haven't seen any way to do this.

Comment: maybe you can hook into compgen somehow? e.g. compgen -c diff prints one completed command name per line for "diff"...

Comment: start with these links [1st](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/tabexpansion.html) [2nd](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/bash-script-using-tab-complete-473112/)

Comment: i don't think so. you can't do that without changing code in bash.

Comment: @Fredrik: This does not really help here, if I understand the question right. We don't want to customize the completion, but we want to execute the completion without the user calling `tab`.

Comment: @jpkotta you can -- ive had to do this a few times.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I actually had to do this to figure out how apt-get autocomplete works on ubuntu (built my own pseudo-repository tool :)

This is a multistep process:

First, `complete -p` will give you a listing of all completions in the form of a set of commands you can run to replicate the configuration.  For example, lets say you want to hunt down the autocomplete for `apt-get`.  Then:

```
$ complete -p | grep apt-get
complete -F _apt_get apt-get
```

This tells you that the shell function _apt_get is called by the completion mechanism.

You need to recreate the special variables used by the function,, namely COMP_LINE (the full line), COMP_WORDS (bash array of all of the arguments -- basically split COMP_LINE), COMP_CWORD (index, should point to last value), COMP_POINT (where within the word you are doing the autocomplete), and COMP_TYPE (this is how you tell it that you want to complete as if you hit tab).

Note: read the manpage for more info -- this is how i figured it out in the first place.  `man bash`

Comment: This shows how to handle the completions that call a function, but there are dozens of other possibilities (e.g. the -o and -A options to `complete`).  This does take care of most cases other than filenames, which are easy enough.

Comment: As of November 2015, this doesn’t show completions that use `complete -F`. The definition for `xrdb`, for example looks like `complete -F _xrdb xrdb` , but `complete -p | grep xrdb` returns nothing